# Entity Framework unique key constraints for email + type

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a parent class called User and two child classes that inherits from User class.

I want to make sure Email is always unique. By adding adding:

```
[Index(IsUnique=true)]
```

I can prevent an email for being used more than one time. 
However, In my case, I would like to be able to use the same email for Guest and Account Owner table, (a user can have both Account Owner and Guest account.

What would be the best solution for this? Is it possible to move the Email property from user and instead use two properties in Account Owner and Guest class? Does EF understand that it's two different types then?

As a side note, In my OnModelCreating function I have added:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<AccountOwner>().ToTable("AccountOwners");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Guest>().ToTable("Guests");
```

So Account Owner and Guest gets it's own table, meaning I can query users from User, AccountOwner and Guest table.

**Parent - User**

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
    }

    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(150)]
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

**Child - Account Owner**

```
public class AccountOwner : User
{
    public AccountOwner()
    {
    }
}
```

**Child - Guest**

```
public class Guest : User
{
    public Guest()
    {
    }
}
```

### How can I make a combined IsUnique constraint on Email and Type?

hi@gmail.com - Account Owner

hi@gmail.com - Guest

Should be allowed.

**Edit**

```
public class AccountLink
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public int AccountOwnerID { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int GuestID { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateStart { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateExpires { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("AccountOwnerID")]
        public virtual AccountOwner AccountOwner { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("GuestID")]
        public virtual Guest Guest { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AccountLinkPermission> AccountLinkPermissions { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the TPH (Table Per Hierarchy) ORM pattern which is the default pattern when you have base class `User` and derived classes like `Guest` and `AccountOwner`.

Remove the code you put in `OnModelCreating` that map `Guest` and `AccountOwner` to their own table.

Don't forget to make `User` class as `abstract` to prevent creating `User` instance because user is `Guest` or `AccountOwner`.

```
public abstract class User
{
    // ...
}
```

Implement your `OnModelCreating` method like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User")
        .Map<Guest>(m => m.Requires("AccountType ").HasValue("Guest"))
        .Map<AccountOwner>(m => m.Requires("AccountType ").HasValue("AccountOwner"));
}
```

Call `Enable-Migrations` for your context, then `Add-Migration Init` for that same context. Then in the generated code `*_Init` add this line:

```
.Index(t => new { t.Email, t.AccountType }, unique: true, name: "IX_EMAIL_ACCOUNTTYPE")
```

at the end of the statement that create `User` table. You must have something like this :

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.User",
    c => new
        {
            UserId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            Email = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 150, unicode: false),
            AccountType = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.UserId)
    .Index(t => new { t.Email, t.AccountType }, unique: true, name: "IX_EMAIL_ACCOUNTTYPE");
```

That is all you have to do.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Don't i need to edit the auto generated code everytime i update my DB? Also, I'm getting this cascading error because I have one to many from User to a table called AccountLinks. I understand why, (Im using 1 table now instead of 3), but how do i fix it? Thanks..

Comment: One more thing..  I have enabled migrations and added the Up and Down migration. How do I implement the .Index?

Comment: No you don't need to edit the generated code everytime unless you delete it and recreate it. The file is generated once. Everytime you call Add-Migration a new different file is created.

You need to explictly configure the relationship with Fluent API between User and AccountLinks into your OnModelCreating.

Comment: I didn't understand the last question about index.

Comment: Aha. So I wont have any problems with code disappearing in the "Up" function when im adding new tables  and stuff? As long as I dont create a new migration file? Dont mind the last question, i figured it out, (my migration file was empty). However the cascading problem is still here. Do you have any suggestion for a quick fix in the OnModelCreating method? My User table has an ICollection<AccountLink> and it seems that there is a delete cascading problem for some reason...

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code about AccountLink class?

Comment: Because your table USer has two foreign key to AccountLink table you have to disable Cascade Delete Action in one of the foreign kye. SQL Database don't allow mutiple cascade deletion. You can choose between AccountOwner or Guest entity. For example if you choose to delete cascade deletion for Guest account you must put in OnModelCreating this line : `modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(p => p.AccountLinks).WithRequired(p => p.Guest).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);`